# Nginx rewrite to proxy_pass server/path

Tags: nginx

is it possible to use Nginx proxy_pass to rewrite URL as below:

```
location /foo {
    proxy_pass http://external-server-IP:8080/some/path/;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yup.

```
location /foo {
    rewrite ^/foo(/.*)$ /some/path$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://external-server-IP:8080;
}
```

Comment: hi , i am getting error : nginx:[emerg] unknown directive " rewrite" in /opt/nginx/nginx.conf:56

Comment: even adding the proxy_pass in second line didn't help .

Comment: Your nginx is somehow missing the *ngx_http_rewrite_module*.